# Double, Integer, Long double

Tags: c, int, double

I apologies in advance if there is a stupid error in this code, but I can't seem to trouble shoot it. My problem is this, I compile with GCC-8 (installed on Mac via home-brew), then execute in the terminal. When using int do define variables s & a, I get zeros as output using the print statements below. If I declare s & a variables as double I still get zeros for the first two print statements, and 1024 for the last print statement. I'm just lost as to what is going on. Appreciate any help!

```
/* square code */
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    int s, a; 
    printf("enter the length of your square \n"); 
    scanf("%f", &s); 
    a= s * s; 
    printf("the area of your square is %f cm using f placeholder \n", a); 
    printf("the area of your square is %lf cm uning fl placeholder\n", a); 
    printf("the area of your square is %d cm using d placeholder \n", a); 
    return(0); 
}
```

Comment: `int a` cannot be succesfully passed to `printf` where `double` is expected, without casting. Similarly with `scanf`, which should be `scanf("%d", &s); ` and no casting can fix this.

Comment: If you go back to your text-book or your lecture notes or tutorial, then I'm sure it would have said something along the line of `"%f"` format with [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) is for the `float` type. Mismatching format and argument type leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: `int s, a; 
....
    scanf("%f", &s);` will generate a waring on many a good compiler when warnings are fully enabled.  Save time and enable all warnings.

Answer (score 0):

```
int s;
scanf("%f", &s);
```

If `s` is an `int` then you need to scan it in like an `int` using `"%d"` instead of `"%f"`. What you are doing is undefined behavior, both in `scanf()` and `printf()`. An integer needs to be scanned and printed as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you use `s` as an `int`, and when you use `scanf` you are using `%f` instead of `%d`. That's the reason why you are getting the first two outputs as a zero.

As for the third output, you will get the expected value, because in that case you are correctly using `%d`. See the code below:

```html
int s;
printf("enter the value");
scanf("%d", &s);
printf("the area of square is=", s*s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the misunderstanding is that you treat the conversion specifiers `%d` and `%f` as defining only the output formatting, regardless of the type of value passed.

Actually each conversion specifier is tightly coupled with a particular type of argument it will accept; For example, `%d` is defined for integral types only, and all other types like floating point or string used together with `%d` will yield undefined behaviour (cf, for example, [cpp-reference of printf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for a more detailed explanation).

So `double f=1.2;printf("%d",f)` will *not* format a floating point value `1.2` as integral (someone might expect `1` being the output); It rather yields undefined behaviour, having any output (even no output), a crash, a... whatever.

Same applies to `scanf`-format specifiers, of course.

So if data type is `int`, use `%d`; if data type is `double`, use `%f`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys thanks so much for the help. Before checking back this morning I tried one more thing, and alas it was a stupid error. 
When declaring "double s,a", I realized my scanf() function was using scanf("%f",s) as opposed to the correct scanf("%lf", s)".

Also thanks for the help for use of %d when using "int s,a".